# How do I stop concurrent PHP scripts from executing the same code at the same time?

Tags: php, wordpress, curl, concurrency

I'm using a service for currency exchange rates which only allows 1000 requests a month, so I have to save the retrieved exchange rates to the database for an hour before updating them with a new request.

However my website has been requesting new exchange rates far more frequently than every hour and I finally realized it's because of concurrent PHP scripts trying to update the rates to the database at the same time. Here is a simplified example of my code:

```
function get_rates()
{
    $rates = get_transient( 'exchange_rates' );
    if( $rates === false ) {

        $ch = curl_init( 'http://examplecurrencyrates.com/rates.json' );
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
        $rates = curl_exec( $ch );

        $cache_time = 3600; // 60 mins
        set_transient( 'exchange_rates', $rates, $cache_time );

        curl_close( $ch );
    }
    return $rates
}
```

How do I make sure there is only one request per hour to update the exchange rates?

Comment: you could make a script exclusively for updating the rates which you use a scheduled task to run it, passing a key parameter or something to make sure only the task runs it and not by other means

Comment: You could write a little file on the server, containing the last update date and time. Every time the script wants to update, you read the file, and if there isn't an hour difference, just exit the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shoud use MySQL table like

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `running` (
  `script` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`script`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

at start script try this query

```
INSERT INTO running ('myscript');
```

if any is already running it second dies

at end of script do

```
DELETE FROM running WHERE script = 'myscript' LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using cronjobs (or any other job scheduler) that will update the rates by running your script every hour.
you got 720 hours per month so you won't exceed the 1000 per month limit.

Comment: This is a good idea but my code is used in a plugin and multiple people will be using it. They expect it to work by simply activating it, requiring them to set up a cronjob won't go down well.

Comment: Ok, so as you can see Ryan suggested using some 'lock' - but you can improve it so it will be locked for at least an hour (store in the lock file the timestamp of the last time you update the data, if it's been more than a hour since last update - retrieve the data again.)

Good luck! :)

Answer (score 1):

One method I use, in similar but slightly different scenarios are lock files.

In my example, I have a script which runs every minute. If this script has a lot of processing to do on a certain run, it might take say 3 minutes - in this time I do not want another 2 instances of this script running and trying to do the same job.

So what I do is at the start of the process, create a lock file, for example:

```
$lock_file = fopen('/lock_file_directory/my_script.lock', 'w');
fclose($lock_file);
```

And at the end of the script, post processing, I add the following:

```
unlink('/lock_file_directory/my_script.lock');
```

This way, during the processing of the script, the lock file is always present.

Now to make this work, at the start of the script - add:

```
if(file_exists('/lock_file_directory/my_script.lock')) { exit; }
```

This means if the lock file exists, the next instance will not run.